Monty Hall Problem - Equivalent LOTP Expansion contradicts direct Bayes calculation
This is the premise of a modified Monty Hall problem:

Consider the standard Monty Hall problem, except that Monty is now a very old man and his memory isn’t as good as it used to be. With probability $p$, he remembers where the car is, and then the game proceeds as in the standard version. But with probability $q = 1 − p$, he forgets where the car is, in which case he chooses randomly, with equal probabilities, which door (other than the contestant’s initial choice) to open. It’s then possible that he reveals the car, which would spoil the game. If the game is spoiled, Monty apologizes and the contestant gets nothing.

The question is:

Monty now opens a door, revealing a goat. Given this information, find the probability that the contestant will get the car.

Here are the events I established: 
Let $C_j$ be the event the car is behind door $j$. 
Let $G_j=C_j^\text{c}$ be the event the car is behind door $j$. 
Let $R$ be the event that Monty remembers. 
Let $F=R^\text{c}$ be the event that Monty forgets. 
Let $M_j$ be the event that Monty opens door $j$. 
I know that the answer is $\frac{p+1}{p+2}$. You can derive that if you solve for
$$P(C_3| M_2, G_2 )= \frac{P(M2, G2|C3)P(C3)}{P(M2,G2)} $$
and expand using LOTP. 
However, my initial reaction was to preliminarily break $P(C_3| M_2, G_2)$ even further with LOTP to $P(R)P(C_3| R, M_2, G_2) + P(F)P(C_3| F, M_2, G_2)$, and add the result of Bayes for both results, but I'd keep on getting different answers; I'm not sure why this LOTP extension doesn't work in this instance. I suspect it has something to do with the denominators, but I can't understand conceptually why I can't go about that process.
I'd really appreciate if someone could walk me through how to calculate $P(R)P(C_3| R, M_2, G_2) + P(F)P(C_3| F, M_2, G_2)$ correctly to get the right answer of $\frac{p+1}{p+2}$, or for someone to explain conceptually and mathematically why that process does not work.

It's not the case that $P(C_3| M_2, G_2)=P(C_3| R, M_2, G_2) + P(C_3| F, M_2, G_2)$. Instead you might write something like $P(C_3| M_2, G_2)=P(C_3\cap R| M_2, G_2) + P(C_3\cap F|M_2, G_2)$, or equivalently $P(C_3| M_2, G_2)=P(R|M_2, G_2)P(C_3| R, M_2, G_2) + P(F|M_2, G_2)P(C_3| F, M_2, G_2)$.

[for comparison, note that the simplest form of the LOTP looks something like $P(A)=P(B)P(A|B)+P(B^C)P(A|B^C)$. It doesn't look like $P(A)=P(A|B)+P(A|B^C)$.]

@JamesMartin sorry I made a typo, it should be $()(_3|,_2,G_2)+()(_3|,_2,_2)$

@JamesMartin in this case, it should be logically equivalent, why still does it not work?

No, it really is the version that I gave in my first comment! You need the terms $P(R|M_2, G_2)$ and $P(F|M_2, G_2)$, not $P(R)$ and $P(F)$ as you have in the version in your most recent comment. The proof of the LOTP is just a few lines - try working through it carefully in this setting with conditioning included, if it's not clear to you why it has the form it does.

If a formula keeps giving you the wrong answer, you look it up to see if you remember it correctly.

There are just three events (and their complements).

$C$: the car is behind whichever door you choose,
$R$: Monty remembers where the car is, and
$G$: A goat is revealed behind whichever door Monty opens.

When the car is behind the door you chose, Monty shall always reveal a goat.
When the car is elsewhere, Monty shall reveal a goat if: he remembers, or he forgets and gets lucky.
The probability that switching wins the car when Monty reveals a goat is:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(C^\complement\mid G)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(C^\complement, R, G)+\mathsf P(C^\complement, R^\complement, G)}{\mathsf P(C^\complement, R, G)+\mathsf P(C^\complement, R^\complement, G)+\mathsf P(C, R, G)+\mathsf P(C,R^\complement, G)}
\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(C^\complement)\left(\mathsf P(R)\mathsf P(G\mid C^\complement, R)+\mathsf P(R^\complement)\mathsf P(G\mid C^\complement, R^\complement)\right)}{\mathsf P(C^\complement)\left(\mathsf P(R)\mathsf P(G\mid C^\complement, R)+\mathsf P(R^\complement)\mathsf P(G\mid C^\complement, R^\complement)\right)+\mathsf P(C)}
\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{\tfrac 23\left(p+\tfrac 12(1-p)\right)}{\tfrac 23\left(p+\tfrac 12(1-p)\right)+\tfrac 13}
\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{p+1}{p+2}
\end{align}$
Alternatively, Monty shall only reveal the car when he forgets, the car is not behind the door you choose, and he is not lucky.
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(C^\complement\mid G) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(G)-\mathsf P(G,C)}{\mathsf P(G)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1-\mathsf P(C^\complement,R^\complement, G^\complement)-\mathsf P(G,C)}{1-\mathsf P(C^\complement,R^\complement, G^\complement)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1-\tfrac 23(1-p)\tfrac 12-\tfrac 13}{1-\tfrac 23(1-p)\tfrac 12}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{p+1}{p+2}\end{align}$
